# GeoPandas not projecting from 4326 to a UTM zone properly?

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas

I am at my wit's end trying to figure out why my data is not being reprojected properly in a geodataframe.

Given this input data, saved in a variable called `power_lines`:

```
{'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {}, 'geometry': {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [[34.059162, -18.676658], [34.193058, -18.677471]]}}]}
```

I create a geodataframe like this, specifying that the data is in `ÈPSG:4326`:

```
power_line_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(power_lines["features"], crs="epsg:4326")
```

When I save this out to file and look at it, it looks like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 34.059162, -18.676658 ], [ 34.193058, -18.677471 ] ] } }
]
}
```

I then reproject the data like this:

```
power_line_gdf = power_line_gdf.to_crs(epsg=3036)
```

And then save it back out to file again, and it looks like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3036" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -4448151.722213513217866, 15265232.02820273861289 ], [ -4436899.918848425149918, 15281201.161440940573812 ] ] } }
]
}
```

It is somewhat obvious from the data itself, but this puts the data way off in another location, way off the west coast of Africa (it should be in Mozambique). Am I missing something blindingly obvious here?

Comment: Did you provide lat,lon when lon,lat was expected?

Comment: I don't think that should be possible, My input is actually the result of a layer being automatically "GeoJSONified" in Leaflet and forwarded to a server

Comment: GeoPandas is probably treating EPSG:4326 as if it is a long/lat projection (it's lat/lon) and not transforming it when converting to GeoJSON which is long/lat. (CRS:84)

Comment: I think it is caused by a known bug in GeoPandas (https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1036). GeoPandas mismatch lat/lon with lon/lat in this case. You have to manually switch coordinates (until the next version will come).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to "solve" it. Instead of initializing the geodataframe with the `crs` keyword argument I initialized it without it and then set it using a dictionary mapping `"init"` to the WGS84 EPSG code like this:

```
power_line_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(power_lines["features"])
power_line_gdf.crs = {"init": "epsg:4326"}
```

After that, I transform the dataframe, again not using the `crs` keyword argument but using the same dictionary structure as before, but mapping it to my target CRS.

```
power_line_gdf = power_line_gdf.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3036'})
```

I think that @martinfleis is correct, because both of these methods are considered valid by geopandas, but one does not apply the trransformation correctly, seemingly because it does not reverse the lat/lon to x/y

Since it is apparently going to be fixed in a later version, I will specify that the version of geopandas on which I was encountering this issue is `0.5.1`